# How can I use external article in my website?

Tags: resources

I would like to know if it is legal to use external article on my website?

I think that if I reference the author it should be OK, but I don't know where to find information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ezinearticles.com

Comment: As your answer was marked as accepted, could you elaborate on your answer? I don't see how 'See ezinearticles.com' answers this question...

Answer (score 1):

By default you must always ask writer of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Some articles are released under some license. In this case you should check details of that license.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you should be OK when you attribute the article to the original author, as most authors like to see their work being shared.

Usually, the author's website will contain copyright statements or license information, which inform you about what you can and cannot do with the content. These should provide you with sufficient information. If you're still in doubt, you can contact the author.

If you've published the article without letting them know (e.g. by automated [trackbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback)), then it's always a good idea to send the author an email, in which you notify him about the use of his article and your reasons to do so. Then the author has a chance to let you know whether he approves of his content being used by you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you are not allowed to reproduce any article without the author's explicit consent. Some authors put their articles in the public domain, others explicitly allow citing or even full reproduction under certain circumstances.
If in doubt, contact the author.